# Is the definite integral $\int\limits_a^b {f(x)dx}$ a function of $f(x)$?

Tags: functions, definite-integrals

I was wondering if definite integrals are functions of their integrands.
For example, if $y=\int\limits_a^b {f(x)dx}$, can we call $y$ a function of $f(x)$ ?

Comment: No, $y$ is a constant, the variable $x$ is "integrated away".

Comment: Well, a definite integral does not depend on whether you use $x$ or $t$ or whatever as a dummy variable. $f(x)=\int_0^1 u\mathrm du$ is a constant function, for instance.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)#Definite_integral

Comment: Yes. The definite integral $f \mapsto \int_a^b f$ is a function of $f$ (though not of $x$).

Comment: I am getting confused by the answers. @okrzysik I was talking about the variable f(x), not x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int : \mathcal R([a,b],\mathbb R)&\longrightarrow \mathbb R\\
f&\longmapsto \int_a^b f
\end{align*}

where $\mathcal R([a,b],\mathbb R)=\{f:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R\mid f\text{ is Riemann integrable}\}$

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more in words?

Comment: That the integral is a function that take a function in argument and send on a real number.